# Setting where a local git branch pulls AND pushes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I am working on my forked repo with 2 main branches:

- master: *pulls* from main_project/master
- bootstrap: *pulls* from collaborator/bootstrap
- **The second remote is a fork also contributing to the main project**

I want the above branches to *pull* from the respective related repos; however, I want them to *push* to `origin/<branch>` (master or bootstrap). I know I can designate a push by `git push <remote> <branch>`, but I want it to be simpler, if possible.

As a follow-up, would *tracking* a branch help in anyway? I am not aware of tracking, although I did read about it via similar SO questions. How would branch tracking affect my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a different `push` url by using the `--push` argument to `git remote set-url`.  E.g.:

```
git remote set-url --push git@github.com:someuser/somerepo
```

For more documentation, see `git help remote`.

Comment: Will that make my current branch push to the remote? I want MY branches to PULL from remotes, but PUSH to my origin.

Comment: Using `--push` just sets the destination for `git push` and does not change the existing source for `git pull`.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. I forgot about this question. But it did help me!